# table index for DISTINCT values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In my stored procedure, I need "Unique" values of one of the columns. I am not sure if I should and if I should, what type of Index I should apply on the table for better performance. No being very specific, the same case happens when I retrieve distinct values of multiple columns.
The column is of String(NVARCHAR) type.

e.g.

> select DISTINCT Column1 FROM Table1;

OR

> select DISTINCT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM Table1;

Comment: I don't think an index will help these queries because every record needs to be scanned to make sure that a given column or set of columns is distinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An index on these specific columns could improve performance by a bit, but just because it will require SQL Server to scan less data (just these specific columns, nothing else). Other than that - a SCAN will always be done. An option would be to create indexed view if you need distinct values from that table.

```
CREATE VIEW Test
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT Column1, COUNT_BIG(*) AS UselessColumn
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Column1;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_Test ON Test (Column1);
GO
```

And then you can query it like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM Test WITH (NOEXPAND);
```

`NOEXPAND` is a hint needed for SQL Server to not expand query in a view and treat it as a table. Note: this is needed for non Enterprise version of SQL Server only.

Comment: Makes sense, Not adding indexes as it may be an overhead during inserts or updates and will save only a little. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had the same issue and found it could be overcome using a Columnstore index:

```
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [CI_TABLE1_Column1] ON [TABLE1]
    ([Column1])
    WITH (DROP_EXISTING = OFF, COMPRESSION_DELAY = 0)
```

Comment: This did it for me... do you know why this is so much faster than a clustered index on the same column?

Comment: My reasoning was that COLUMNSTORE indexes only hold the data in the columns specified and not the pointer to the primary key, so would likely only hold individual data values and the number of instances, so having a count of each value (if there is only one column). It worked, but if someone has a different explanation, I'd like to hear it.